# Find the cardinality of the following sets of sequences

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

Find the cardinality of the following sets of sequences:
(a) $$\left\{(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb Q} \in \mathbb Q ^{ \mathbb N}: \forall n \in N ( a_n+a_{n+1} = a_{n+2})\right\}$$
(b) $$\left\{(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb Q} \in \mathbb Q ^{ \mathbb N}: \forall n \in N (a_n \in \mathbb Z  \wedge  a_n+a_{n+1} = |a_{n+2}|)\right\}$$
I have a problem with this task because I completely do not understand how I can deduce the power of this sequences from this information.
 I knew that $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb Q} \in \mathbb Q ^{ \mathbb N}$ means that sequence $a_n$ belongs to function $f$ defined as $f: \mathbb N \rightarrow \mathbb Q$ so for each $a_n$ I have the words which are measurable. What is more in both sub-points I knew three words behave in relation to each other.
 Unfortunately I still do not have any knowledge how to do it. Can I get some tips?

Comment: I would think an element of $\mathbb Q^{\mathbb N}$ would be a sequence of rationals (i.e. a function $\mathbb N\to\mathbb Q$). As such, the notation $(a_n)_{n\in \mathbb Q}$ does not make sense. $n$ is in $\mathbb N,$ not $\mathbb Q.$ Also, by "power" do you mean cardinality? (I also do not know what the jargon "sub-point", "word" or "measurable"  mean in this context.)

Comment: Define power of set of sequences.

Comment: @WilliamElliot "Power" is an old-fashioned synonym for "cardinality".

Comment: A sequence index with rational numbers is a strange sequence.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen yes, you have right that this notation does not make sense, but the content is saved correctly so I am not responsible for the shortcomings of the author of the task. When it comes to my vocabulary: power is cardinality, sub-point is (a) and (b) so I talk about my two task, word is $a_{1},a_{2},...a_{n}$, measurable mean $ \in \mathbb Q$

Answer (score 0):

I would think an element of $\mathbb Q^{\mathbb N}$ would be a sequence of rationals (i.e. a function $\mathbb N\to\mathbb Q$). As such, the notation $(a_n)_{n\in \mathbb Q}$ does not make sense. $n$ is in $\mathbb N,$ not $\mathbb Q.$ Also, by "power" do you mean cardinality? (I also do not know what the jargon "sub-point", "word" or "measurable"  mean in this context.)